# Split strings in a list of lists

Tags: python, string, list, split

I currently have a list of lists:

```
[['Hi my name is'],['What are you doing today'],['Would love some help']]
```

And I would like to split the strings in the lists, while remaining in their current location. For example

```
[['Hi','my','name','is']...]..
```

How can I do this?

Also, if I would like to use a specific of the lists after searching for it, say I search for "Doing", and then want to append something to that specific list.. how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to create new list of lists with all the sentences split:

```
[lst[0].split() for lst in list_of_lists]
```

Now you can loop through this and find the list matching a condition:

```
for sublist in list_of_lists:
    if 'doing' in sublist:
        sublist.append('something')
```

or searching case insensitively, use `any()` and a generator expression; this will the minimum number of words to find a match:

```
for sublist in list_of_lists:
    if any(w.lower() == 'doing' for w in sublist):
        sublist.append('something')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [['Hi my name is'],['What are you doing today'],['Would love some help']]
```

use

```
[i[0].split() for i in list1]
```

then you will get the output like

```
[['Hi', 'my', 'name', 'is'], ['What', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today'], ['Would', 'love', 'some', 'help']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [['Hi my name is'],['What are you doing today'],['Would love some help']]

for x in l:
    l[l.index(x)] = x[0].split(' ')

print l
```

Or simply:

```
l = [x[0].split(' ') for x in l]
```

Output

```
[['Hi', 'my', 'name', 'is'], ['What', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today'], ['Would', 'love', 'some', 'help']]
```