# python: split items in each sublist

Tags: python, split, sublist

I have the following sublists:

```
lst=[['a,b,c,d,e'],['f,g,h'] ]
```

and I would like to obtain the following outcome:

```
lst=[['a','b','c','d','e'],['f','g','h']]
```

but the following line

```
lst1=[y for x in lst for y in x.split(',')]
print(lst1)
```

produces this error:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

How should I fix this problem ?

Comment: question: could the sublists contain multiple strings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split strings in a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927859/split-strings-in-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: `list1 = [x[0].split(',') for x in lst]`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this instead -

```
lst1 = [entry.split(',') for sublist in lst for entry in sublist]
```

As per your comment, if you have both `:` and `,` as delimiters - you can do

```
lst1 = [entry.replace(':',',').split(',') for sublist in lst for entry in sublist]
```

This will start getting difficult to read as the number of delimiters increases - in which case you can use the `re.split` as pointed out by @Ajax1234

Comment: thank you, but what if I had lst=[['a:b,c,d,e'],['f:g,h'] ], how do you replace ':' with ',' ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple method:

```
lst = [['a,b,c,d,e'],['f,g,h']]

list1 = [x[0].split(',') for x in lst]
print(list1)
```

Output:
`[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h']]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.split` to handle multiple delimiter values:

```
import re
lst=[['a:b,c,d,e'],['f:g,h']]
result = [re.split(':|,', i) for [i] in lst]
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h']]
```